# What's the logic behind thread selection from thread pools in the Java concurrent API?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, java.util.concurrent

The [Java concurrent API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) offers many useful libraries and features that make working with async and multithreaded control flows much easier. One of those features is [Thread Pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

Earlier today I was experimenting with the concurrency API and noticed some odd patterns regarding thread selection from a thread pool. They got me wondering what the logic is behind thread selection. Below is some sample code to perhaps give you an example of what I'm talking about. You will notice the pattern in the thread name (inside the `[` `]`) when the program logs each `tick`. Although, the pattern might not appear on JDK builds other than Oracle JDK 1.8.0_161 on a 64 bit Windows 10 machine.

Regardless, my question has less to do with any coincidental pattern, and is instead about the process of selecting a thread from a thread pool. The pattern leaves me to believe that it's not entirely random, so what is the logic behind this selection? Thanks. :)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // create a ScheduledExecutorService with a Thread Pool of 7 threads
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(7);
    log("go");
    // starts a timer of 30 seconds, shutting down ses afterwards
    ses.schedule(() -> call(ses), 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // starts the ticker
    ses.schedule(() -> tick(ses, 1), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

// ticks once per second, logging the current tick counter. (i.e, counts
// by 1 each second) ticking ends when ses is shutdown.
public static void tick(ScheduledExecutorService ses, int count)
{
    if (!ses.isShutdown())
    {
        log("tick %d", count);
        ses.schedule(() -> tick(ses, count + 1), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}

// called when it's time to shutdown ses.
public static void call(ScheduledExecutorService ses)
{
    log("done");
    ses.shutdown();
}

// formats and logs the given message alongside a timestamp and the name
// of the executing thread
public static void log(String s, Object...args)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String time = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    String thread = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    String message = String.format(s, args);
    String log = String.format("%s [%s] - %s", time, thread, message);
    System.out.println(log);
}
```

Comment: You have actually created a ScheduledThreadPool which is far from "truly random"   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Worker threads belonging to the same thread pool are completely interchangeable. Why do you want to know the identity of any given worker thread?

Comment: @besmirched No reason, simply curious.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the OpenJDK source code?  http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java

Answer (score 0):

The `ScheduledThreadPool` you created has a `DelayQueue` inside. When you submit a task, it always creates a new worker thread which will keep taking a task from `DelayQueue`.

the code when you submit a task,the new thread keeps taking a task

```
//getTask() method calls DelayQueue#take()
while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
       ......
       task.run();
       ......
}
```

the `take()` method returns a task if `getDelay` method return zero, otherwise the worker thread will be Waiting for the countdown to end.When the time arrives,it will wake up worker thread to get task.

the code of DelayQueue#take()

```
/**
 * Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary
 * until an element with an expired delay is available on this queue.
 *
 * @return the head of this queue
 * @throws InterruptedException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E take() throws InterruptedException {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        for (;;) {
            E first = q.peek();
            if (first == null)
                available.await();
            else {
                long delay = first.getDelay(NANOSECONDS);
                if (delay <= 0)
                    return q.poll();
                first = null; // don't retain ref while waiting
                if (leader != null)
                    available.await();
                else {
                    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
                    leader = thisThread;
                    try {
                        available.awaitNanos(delay);
                    } finally {
                        if (leader == thisThread)
                            leader = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (leader == null && q.peek() != null)
            available.signal();
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

when you submit 7 tasks,there are 7 worker threads are waiting to be woken up. 
so thread selection depends on Wake-up strategy,Generally, it wakes up according to the order of waiting queues.